# Font Awesome 5: how to use inside parent svg with vue-fontawesome

Tags: svg, vue.js, font-awesome

I'm using Vue.js to generate an svg inside a template.

I've set up [vue-fontawesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome) to use Font Awesome 5 with Vue.js.
It works by replacing i.e. `<font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'check']" />` with an inline SVG in the html `<template>`.

What would be the best way to use it inside another SVG? Is it OK to have a `<svg>` element inside a parent `<svg>`? And what would be the best way to resize it? Via `transform="scale(0.5)"`?

Other possible ways to use FA5 inside an SVG:

- import faMyIcon.js and then only grab the path and then insert it inside the parent svg.
- use a web font and its Unicode code (à la FontAwesome 4).

What is the recommended way?

Comment: <svg> elements can be nested.

Comment: Indeed you are right. It works out of the box with `<font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'check']" width="15" height="15" :style="{ 'color': myColorProp }"/>`